# How do I do 'validates_presence_of' new column in Devise - other than email & pw on the User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This is my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
                 :email_regexp =>  /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_token, :category_ids
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
    validates_confirmation_of   :password

end
```

What I want to do is to enforce the presence of 'category_ids' on an 'activated' account.

I am doing [Email Only Sign-up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How%20To%3a%20Email-only%20sign-up) - which is important to note, because it is a two-stage process. The first time a user enters their email address, they are sent an activation email - with a link to `Confirmations` controller.

The view for that `Confirmations Controller` has the additional details that need to be validated.

If I just did a regular `validates_presence_of` on the `User` model, then when a user initially submits just an email address - Rails would fail it (which I don't want).

The user should:

1. Enter email address
2. Click confirmation/activation link in email
3. Fill in name, password and select a category.
4. Submit.

Step #3, Devise enforces presence_of_validation for name & pw. But not my custom item called `category`.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `:on => :update` option to `validates_presence_of`, and it won't validate on creation:

Example

```
 validates_presence_of :category_ids, :on => :update
```

Comment: This still overrides the Devise validations, at least initially. How do I add this validation check to the Devise checks?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. 

Devise does its validations just like any Active Record model. It won't override anything.

Comment: Well..so what happens is, once I add this, it automatically checks for `category_ids` first...if it doesn't see it - it reports that a category is missing. Even if the other fields are blank. So the issue is, if I submit a form with everything else blank, it only see that this one is blank at first and returns 1 error, when it should be returning 3 errors (which include the other fields).

Comment: I have added an application on that shows this

https://github.com/rodrigoflores/example_required_fields

If you sign up, and go to /users/edit, the form will work as expected. Maybe your problem is not related with Devise (if possible, try to reproduce it on a vanilla rails app, and then I can take a look)